# Show Table content in Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, treeview, browser

I created a "Help" function in my application, that opens a dialog, looking like this:

[image: Application Screenshot]

The control on the left side, is a `TreeView`. The control on the right side, is a `WebBrowser`. The `WebBrowser` is filled with a Word-document, converted to `.mhtml` (HTML with images included).

I am using a table as you can see on the image, the links are clickable and the user will be directed to the location on the document. Is there a way to show that table in the `TreeView` on the left? If it is possible, can someone give me an example which shows me how to get the wanted result?

**EDIT:**

```
<h2 style=3D'mso-list:l9 level2 lfo12'><a name=3D"_Toc353271009"><![if !sup=
portLists]><span
style=3D'mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin'><span
style=3D'mso-list:Ignore'>2.2<span style=3D'font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&=
nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]>Eerste keer opstarten Liveduiven Client</a><=
/h2>
```

The code above, is a link from the table.

Another link for making it more clear:

```
style='mso-no-proof:yes'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
 <p class=MsoToc1 style='tab-stops:22.0pt right dotted 481.45pt'><span
 class=MsoHyperlink><span style='mso-no-proof:yes'><a href="#_Toc353271007">2<span
 style='color:windowtext;text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'><span
 style='mso-tab-count:1'>       </span></span>DE LIVEDUIVEN CLIENT<span
 style='color:windowtext;display:none;mso-hide:screen;text-decoration:none;
 text-underline:none'><span style='mso-tab-count:1 dotted'>. </span></span>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the HTML structure? Also: Is it XHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know structure of your html content,but i write an example (that how can you do this):

**Navigate To your url**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft");
        }
```

**Get Element of your page subject**

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get header of subject
            foreach (HtmlElement elementintable in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("toc").All)
            {
                if (elementintable.TagName == "A")
                {
                    //insert key and string to each node
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(elementintable.GetAttribute("href").Split('#')[1], elementintable.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Get Selected Node Key**

```
        private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //navigate to selected anchor
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(e.Node.Name).ScrollIntoView(true);
        }
```

**Result**

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Navibate To your url
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft");
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get header of subject
            foreach (HtmlElement elementintable in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("toc").All)
            {
                if (elementintable.TagName == "A")
                {
                    //insert key and string to each node
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(elementintable.GetAttribute("href").Split('#')[1], elementintable.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }

        private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //navigate to selected anchor
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(e.Node.Name).ScrollIntoView(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I two questions about your answer: 1) why does the webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted doesn't get called when the Document is succesfully loaded in the webBrowser control? 2) does it matter if I use webBrowser1.Navigate(path) or webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(path); ?

Comment: First: Did you add  `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;`  after  `InitializeComponent();`?<br>sec:Note that setting the URL is exactly the same as calling the Navigate() function. Navigate takes a string as an argument as the URL, eliminating the step of converting your URL to a string.